# Executing stored procedure based on a variable conditions

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Environment: Oracle SQL Developer

Scenario: To compare a measure from 2 different tables and run a stored procedure if the condition satisfies

Tried to store the measure of each table inside a variable and compare the variables and execute the stored procedure

```
--For Variable1
Declare 
  Variable1 int;
Begin 
  select sum(sales) from table1 into Variable1;
end;

--For Variable2
Declare 
  Variable2 int;
Begin 
  select sum(sales) from table2 into Variable2;
end

--Creating stored procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1 as 
BEGIN
  IF (Variable1=Variable2) THEN
    PROC2()
  END IF;    
END Proc1;
```

1. I'm unable to store the value inside `Variable1` and `Variable2`
2. I'm unable to run the stored procedure using condition

Comment: You should write everything inside the stored procedure Proc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Syntax is `select ... into ... from ..`

If you want to use your variables in `proc1` you should define them in that proc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1 as 
  Variable1 int;
  Variable2 int;    
BEGIN
  select sum(sales) into Variable1 from table1 ;
  select sum(sales) into Variable2 from table2 ;

  IF (Variable1=Variable2) THEN
    PROC2();
  END IF;
END Proc1;
```

Or you can can pass the values as parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1(Variable1 in int, Variable2 in int) as 

BEGIN
  -- Using Parameter values   
  IF (Variable1=Variable2) THEN
    PROC2();
  END IF;

END Proc1;
/

Declare
  Variable1 int;
  Variable2 int;
Begin 
  select sum(sales)  into Variable1 from table1;
  select sum(sales)  into Variable2 from table2;
  -- pass values into the procedure
  proc1( Variable1,Variable2 );   
END;
```

/

Answer (score 0):

Your variables only live for the duration of each PL/SQL block.
So if you want to compare variable1 and variable2 you'll have to put them in the same PL/SQL block.
That would give you :

```
Declare
 Variable1 int;
 Variable2 int;
Begin 
select sum(sales) into Variable1 from table1;
select sum(sales) into Variable2 from table2;
IF Variable1 = Variable2 THEN
  PROC2;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Not that all this code can be in an anonymous PL/SQL block.
You can also store it in a procedure if you prefer.

Comment: i updated after "hotfix" answer, it's true that you have to put the INTO keyword before the FROM.